# Merge arrays in document with mongo aggregation

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have one requirement where i need to do aggregation on two records both have two array fields with different value. What I need that when I do aggregation on these records the result should have one array with unique values from both different arrays. Here is example :

First record

```
 { Host:"abc.com" ArtId:"123", tags:[ "tag1", "tag2" ], msg:["msg1", "msg2"] }
```

Second record

```
{ Host:"abc.com" ArtId:"123", tags:[ "tag2", "tag3" ], msg:["msg2", "msg3"]  }
```

After aggregation on host and artid i need result like this:

```
 { Host: "abc.com", ArtId: "123", count :"2", tags:[ "tag1", "tag2", "tag3" ],msg:["msg1","msg2", "msg3"] }
```

I tried `$addToset` in group statement but it gives me like this tags :`[["tag1","tag2"],["tag2","tag3"]]` `msg:[["msg1","msg2"],["msg2","msg3"]]`

Could you please help me how i can achieve this in aggregation or i should use code to parse array in my java code to create single array from nested array as i think for two array field i need to do aggregation multiple times

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by using `$unwind` first

So

```
db.collection.aggregate([...,
                         {$unwind:"$tags"},
                         {$unwind:"$msg"},
                         {$group: { ..., tags:{ $addToSet: "$tags" },
                                         msg:{ $addToSet: "$msg" },...}},
                         ...])
```

As an explanation: `$addToSet` creates an array from the unique values you put into it. In your case those are arrays therefore it builds an array of arrays.

The `$unwind` Operator unwinds an array by creating a duplictate of the document for each value in that array containing only that value and not the array (for example `tags:tag1`). So `$addToSet` gets single values not arrays to build into a new array.

Comment: I am not sure with it but if you unwind before group and use count with $sum which this will give you you result added with each unwind

Comment: You are right it would count each unwinded document in the group. I hadn't seen the sum in the result. Could your add your complete aggregation pipeline to question? There are ways to make a correct sum even with unwind, the question is where to best modify the pipeline for this.

Comment: Just look at your previous question the answer is the same just two unwinds